# Conversion of XML file to CSV

Tags: xml, xslt, csv

I would like to run the following input file:

```
<structure>
  <object>
    <property name="DOC">ABC</property>
    <property name="VERS">001</property>
    <property name="REV">-</property>
    <property name="NAME">Peter</property>
  </object>
</structure>

<structure>
  <object>
    <property name="DOC">ABC</property>
    <property name="VERS">001</property>
    <property name="REV">1</property>
    <property name="NAME">Carl</property>
  </object>
</structure>
```

to get the following output with saxon processor:

```
DOC,VERS,REV,NAME
ABC,001,-,Peter
ABC,001,1,Carl
```

Any ideas how to format the XSL file.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read the [FAQ] and [Ask] for hints on writing good questions.  You have just asked someone to do your work for you without showing any evidence you've tried to solve the problem yourself.  That is generally discouraged here.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Are there any learning materials or How To's available you would recommend to read through? I would like to learn more about XSLT. Thanks.